# Problems with select() in an simple selfmade p2p program to exchange "musicdata" with udp

Tags: c++, c, select, udp, p2p

heyho,

i'm trying to make a simple p2p program, that should be able to let at least 3 peers exchange musicdata (author/title) that is stored in 1 file per peer through port 50001-50010. to say it bluntly it's homework and we never really talked about p2p nor did i found any usefull and simple p2p examples without special libraries etc. with beej's guide to network programming and some other sources i got an already halfway working program but i have 1 big problem:

my select call is for the whole loop just for the first client/peer every time 1 for all the other it is just 0 and so they will never receive any data

my p2p code:

```
case 6:
{
    if(!filename.empty())
    {
        time_t start, now;
        time(&start);
        double elapsedtime = 0;
        char *recvbuf;
        char *sendbuf;
        recvbuf = new char[1024];
        sendbuf = new char[1024];
        int recvfd, sendfd,err, port;
        int errormarker = 0;
        if((recvfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0)) == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "Error setting socket\n";
            errormarker =1;
        }
        if(errormarker ==1)
            break;
        struct sockaddr_in server_address;
        server_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
        server_address.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        server_address.sin_port = htons(50001);
        for (int i =0; i<=9;i++)
        {
            port = 50001+i;
            errormarker = bind(recvfd,(sockaddr*) &server_address, sizeof   (server_address));
            if(errormarker ==-1)
                server_address.sin_port = htons(server_address.sin_port+1);
            else
                break;
        }
        if(errormarker == -1)
        {
            std::cout << "all ports are used, please wait a minute and try again\n";
            break;
        }
        std::cout << "Searching for other musicdata owners\n";
        fd_set readset;
        while (elapsedtime < 15)
        {
            if(errormarker != 0)
                break;
            memset(recvbuf, 0, sizeof(recvbuf));
            memset(sendbuf, 0, sizeof(sendbuf));
            struct timeval tv;
            tv.tv_sec =0;
            tv.tv_usec = rnd(10000,50000);
            FD_ZERO(&readset);
            FD_SET(recvfd, &readset);
            int result = select(recvfd + 1, &readset, NULL, NULL, &tv);
            std::cout << result << "\n";
            if (result >0)
            {
                result = recvfrom(recvfd, recvbuf, 1024, NULL,NULL,NULL);
                if (result != -1)
                {
                    buftofile(recvbuf,filename);
                    addnewdata(filename);
                }
                else
                    std::cout << "error receiving data \n";
            }
            filetobuf(sendbuf,filename);
            for(int i = 50001; i<=50010;i++)
            {
                struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
                memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
                hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
                hints.ai_socktype =SOCK_DGRAM;
                std::string s_port = to_string(i);
                err = getaddrinfo(NULL,s_port.c_str(),&hints,&servinfo);
                for(p=servinfo;p!=NULL;p=p->ai_next)                                
                {
                    if(i == port)
                    {
                        err = sendto(recvfd, sendbuf,strlen(sendbuf), 0, p->ai_addr,p->ai_addrlen);
                        continue;
                    }
                    if((sendfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        err=sendto(sendfd,sendbuf,strlen(sendbuf), 0, p->ai_addr,p->ai_addrlen);
                        close(sendfd);                              
                    }
                }
                freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
            }
            time(&now);
            elapsedtime=difftime(now,start);
        }
        close(recvfd);

    }
    else
        std::cout << "Error, please choose a file to save your data first!" << std::endl;
}
break;
```

the functions are all tested and work as they should.

(on a sitenote i got a little irregularity that startles me slightly:
when i run all 3 clients and the first one gets all the data he gets everytime the same line missing exactly 3 characters --- every time again --- i'm running the programm from one pc and can't completely understand, why that happens every time (i guess i should add a start- and an endsign to remove the problem, but the fact, that the same line comes every time fascinates me though). Is there an explanation to that phenomen?)

thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Aside from the parenthetical on the bottom, what is your question?

Comment: i can't understand, why my select() is for the first client straight 1 every time and for all other clients it just stays 0//times out --> the first one gets all the data, but the rest gets nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of checking which socket from the read set received data, you are directly calling recvfrom on recvfd descriptor. You need to check all of them in a loop.

This is what i could gather in a quick review.

But [here](http://forum.codecall.net/topic/64205-concurrent-tcp-server-using-select-api-in-linux-c/) is a tcp based example i wrote a long time ago. Your's is udp but you should be able to find the source of your problem easily.

P.S. There was one mistake in code that some one pointed out and fixed in the comments of the post.

Comment: the recvfd is the only socket i'm putting in the set for select, so if select returns 1, that socket is the only one, that could recv something, i will look through your exapmle

Comment: Well why are you using select if you have a single descriptor to monitor? Select is only needed when you have multiple ones - each connected to a different client (or in case of udp logically used with a different client) and you want to be notified whenever data is received on any one of them.

Comment: the only reason i'm using select, is too  have some kind of time window i'm able to receive data before sending. as mentioned before, we had not that much information about p2p and select looked like a tool that would work.
my exact problem with select is anyway, that it stays for the first client the whole time 1 (so he receives the data) and for the other it is just 0